# TCPDF getAliasNbPages - Get total pages of produced file

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm using the follwing TCPDF code to generate PDFs with the writeHTML function. I have the page number footer function which puts page numbers at the bottom of each page as the pdf total pages grows. I'm trying to find a way at the end of creating all the pages to determine how many total pages the produced document has so that i can store that information into a variable and submit that data to a DB.

I've tried:

```
$total = $pdf->getAliasNbPages();
```

but doesnt work, Any ideas?

Thanks

```
// PAGE NUMBERED FOOTER

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
    $this->SetFont('Calibri', '', 8);
        // Page number

    $pageNumbers = 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages();

        $this->Cell(0, 10, $pageNumbers, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }

}


$html = 'html content';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the getNumPages function instead:

```
$total = $pdf->getNumPages();
```

Note that this counts the amount of pages that have been created so far using the Addpage() function. So if you want the total amount of pages declare it after your last use of Addpage()

Answer (score 1):

$pdf->Cell(0, 10,'{:ptp:}', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of pages, use **$this->getAliasNbPages()** as chown in this example https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/

Comment: This is the canon way to do this in the header or footer. I don't know why you got a downvote. It looks like the question is not the whole code either as I don't see $pdf = new MYPDF(); I like your answer better than the selected answer. Using the note the selected answers author left can work following close attention to his caveat but if not careful it will not show the running total properly. Cheers to you and at least now you're not negative as your way is better way to do this.